# How to make vline and hline stop at a certain point in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
# load ggplot2 library
library(ggplot2)

# create example data
x <- rnorm(50)
y <- x + rnorm(50)

# create ggplot object with equal axis lengths
p <- ggplot(data = data.frame(x, y), aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_point() + geom_abline()
p <- p + scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(-3,3, by=1),limits = c(-3,3))
p <- p + scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(-3,3, by=1),limits = c(-3,3))

# add vertical and horizontal lines
p <- p + geom_vline(xintercept = -1, color = "blue") +
  geom_hline(yintercept = -1, color = "blue")
```

[image]

I want the lines to go no higher than -1 on either axis, but can't seem to figure out how to do it. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use two `geom_segment`s with specifying the right x and y coordinates like this:

```r
# load ggplot2 library
library(ggplot2)

# create example data
x <- rnorm(50)
y <- x + rnorm(50)

# create ggplot object with equal axis lengths
p <- ggplot(data = data.frame(x, y), aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_point() + geom_abline()
p <- p + scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(-3,3, by=1),limits = c(-3,3))
p <- p + scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(-3,3, by=1),limits = c(-3,3))

# add vertical and horizontal lines
p + geom_segment(x = -Inf, xend = -1, y = -1, yend = -1, color = "blue") +
  geom_segment(x = -1, xend = -1, y = -Inf, yend = -1, color = "blue")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-04-08 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>